# What to do when someone answers your question in the comments?... and then deletes it

Tags: discussion, comments

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569817/align-multiple-plots-in-ggplot2-when-some-have-legends-and-others-dont) that received useful answers, but none of them was fully satisfying.

As I refined my question, I offered a bounty to attract better answers and that worked.

However, one user gave a very good solution in the comments of my question (it was quite short and should have been detailed in an actual answer). I upvoted his comment and told him that was the solution I was expecting.

Then, this user deleted his comments (and the useful links he wrote) and just left.

What should I do? Should I post an answer myself (and what happens with my bounty in that case)?

Is it possible to find the deleted comments to help me write a good answer?

Comment: How long ago did this happen? Maybe he decided that he should write up a complete answer, and deleted his comment while preparing said answer.

Comment: @Cody Posted 16 hours ago, deleted 9 hours ago.

Comment: Hmm, well, maybe he's a *very* slow typist. :-)

Comment: More likely that they have discovered some error in their ways which Ben hasn't yet thought through… or… who knows… they forgot their keys or something.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This was the comment:

> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231876/aligning-setting-width-of-margin-figure-region-in-ggplot2/41242871#41242871) copied from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489250/specifying-ggplot2-panel-width#5492301) might help (but after equating widths use `grid.arrange(grobs=gl)`)

<sub>(anonymous to protect the innocent; if they don't want to be associated with it, let them)</sub>

Some users feel there's a bit of an honour system with regards to who gets to write up an answer, but especially in this case this shouldn't stop you. What we want on SO is *answers to questions*, and no identity politics. If nobody else has provided this solution to the problem yet, by all means, please write up an answer and post it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was it deleted by op or a moderator?

Comment: By OP themselves.

Comment: @deceze Quick question, are moderators allowed to see and bring back deleted posts & comments.

Comment: @Mango Even non-moderators with enough reputation can see and vote to undelete a post. Moderators can do it unilaterally. Only moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: I have no experience with r, but are the links in the comments dupes? Because if they are I'd expect a dupe closure rather than that user to write up an answer just reiterating content.

Comment: @The Yeah, I have no idea and will have to defer to the [tag:r] people for judgement…

Comment: @deceze I was commenting more to point out that this should be done instead of answering if they answer it

Comment: I understand what you mean from context, but you realize that "identity politics" has a very different (and potentially controversial) meaning in general, right?

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, wasn't the best choice of words, but a better one didn't come to mind. Feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I would say it is a dupe, there are plenty of "r align multiple ggplot" posts.

Answer (score 12):

> Then, this user deleted his comments (and the useful links he wrote)
>   and just left.

Very curious, but that's his prerogative. In that case you can't really do much, comments are ephemeral and not really meant to stay anyways. It could be that he didn't even delete the comment himself, but that it was flagged and deleted by a moderator. (Unlikely in this case, but possible)

> What should I do? Should I post an answer myself (and what happens
>   with my bounty in that case)?

There's nothing stopping you from writing a comprehensive and decent answer yourself. You can do that and even accept your own answer (that will not pin it to the top, though).

You'll either have to manually award the bounty to the next best answer (in your opinion) or let it expire. This causes it to be auto awarded to the best answer by votes that has at least a score of +2. If no other answer has a score of at least +2 and you let the bounty expire, nobody gets the bounty reputation.

> Is it possible to find the deleted comments to help me write a good
>   answer?

Probably not. Only moderators can see deleted comments, and I'm not sure a moderator would provide the deleted comment if you flagged. But if you absolutely want to see that comment, raise a custom flag on your post asking for it. That flag may get declined though, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Note that to be auto awarded a bounty, the answer needs to be posted after the bounty started, and will only be awarded half the reputation

Answer (score 12):

What I would do in this case is write it up myself but credit the original comment and tick the community wiki checkbox at the bottom. That way I am not "taking credit" for someone else's answer but at the same time I'm making it available for everyone to use.

I've even done that on random questions where I've seen an answer in the comments that should be an answer. Especially if the question is in the "unanswered" queue.

In this case though the comment isn't really a fully fledged answer, it just points you in the right direction. Considering the extra effort needed to compile a full answer together I would most likely just post it as a non-wiki answer with a credit given to the original comment.

Comment: That's what I did in the end: I cited the comment and wrote the answer myself